# Confused: implement multiple interfaces in Go

Tags: go, interface

In the below code the type `ErrNegativeSqrt` implements both `Stringer` and `error` interfaces. Since in `Sqrt` method the return type is `fmt.Stringer`, I would except the execution result to be:

> 0 nil
>
> 0 Impl Stringer type

But the actual result is the following, why?

> 0 nil
>
> 0 Impl error type

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func Sqrt(x ErrNegativeSqrt) (float64, fmt.Stringer) {
    if x < 0 {
        return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(x)
    }
    return 0, nil
}

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) String() string {
    return "Impl Stringer type"
}

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return "Impl error type"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation for Package `fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) states that:

> ... special formatting
>   considerations apply for operands that implement certain interfaces.
>   In order of application:
>
> ...
>
> 3. If the %v verb is used with the # flag (%#v) and the operand implements the GoStringer interface, that will be invoked.
>
> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a
>   string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked ...
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked ...

Since you are using `fmt.Println`, rules 4 and 5 come into play, which prefers to call `Error()` over `String()`

Answer (score 3):

You're ignoring the fact that your function returns a `fmt.Stringer` by passing the resulting value to `fmt.Println` as an `interface{}`.

You see the result from the `Error()` method only because the `fmt` package checks for the `error` interface before it checks for the `fmt.Stringer` interface.